# Velocity property does not working

Tags: velocity

I am using velocity in my project, and I have a list with icon for each item in list, but I want to set de class icon according what come from my database, to make my menu dynamic.

```
                    <li>
                    #foreach($item in $navegacao)
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="with_sub"><img src="#link("resources/theme/mango/img/icons/packs/fugue/16x16/application-form.png")" alt="" height="16" width="16">$item.nome</a>
                    <ul class="sub" style="display: none;">
                        #foreach($nav in $item.navegacoes)
                            <li class="with-icon"><a href="ui_grid.html"><span class="icon icon-th"></span>$nav.nome</a></li>
                        #end
                    </ul>
                    #end
                </li>
```

I have this code `<span class="icon icon-th"></span>`, but instead of `icon icon th`, I want to set a new class, I tried `<span class=$nav.classIcon></span>` but its not working. My objects `navegacao` and `item.navegacoes` is coming right in my session.

Comment: Try putting quotes around the `class` attriute, and using the formal Velocity reference notation, i.e. `<span class="${nav.classIcon}" </span>`.  If that doesn't help, print the value of `$nav.classIcon` to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Evan, it's work I was forgetting the quotes.

Comment: Good deal, I have posted this as an answer, could you please accept?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I was a little absent from stackoverflow.com, I accepted your answer, is that correct the way I accepted? I am new here, Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that will do it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `class` attribute is missing the enclosing quotes; since you're setting multiple classes, these are required (and should really be there in any case).